# Pinch and Pan to Crop UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, crop, pinch

I want to add a Pinch and Pan gesture that will crop the UIImage views on my ViewController. To crop the images, just pinch/pan the appropriate image and it will resize.

I currently have the Take Pic and Choose Image buttons grab the appropriate images into the UIImageView boxes accordingly, but I want to be able to pinch and pan to size and crop the image in the view.

I want the box to stay fixed at its current size, and the image within will be the one resizing and cropping.

PS. I am using storyboard

Here is a screenshot of what I have.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/chkk5.png

I was thinking that the right direction would be to add a swipe and pan gesture to each uiimageviews in storyboard, but not sure what to do after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My general strategy for this in the past has to been place the UIImageView inside another UIView (in order to clip it) and add a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` and a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to the parent UIView. When you receive events for either of these you apply the appropriate transformation to the `transform` property of the UIImageView.

When scaling, for example, you would do the following:

```
-(void)scale:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)pinch
{
 float scale = pinch.scale;
 imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(imageView.transform, scale, scale);
 pinch.scale = 1;
}
```

The final step of reseting the scale is important because you are simply scaling the existing transform each time rather than a base identity transform. You should find that you will be able to handle translating the transform by using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and its `translationInView:` method (remember you will also have to reset this with `setTranslationInView:CGPointZero`.

Finally, in order to get a cropped/clipped `UIImage` out you can either capture the view's contents (I believe the transform property is only respected on iOS 7+) or alternatively render the UIImage into a `CGContextRef`, and using the same transform to transform the `CGContextRef`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use below link...

[Crop image](http://code4app.net/ios/Crop-Image-Controller/518a60776803fac26b000001)